# MFPCreateMediaPlayer returning uknown/undocumented error code 0x80070002 on call

Tags: ruby, winapi, dll

In RPG Maker VX Ace, I'm attempting to write my own video player script out of complete boredom, however, I've run into a bit of a snag. When the game tries to call MFPCreateMediaPlayer from my script, it results in an error code(0x80070002 which doesn't exist in the full list of error codes documented [here.](https://www.megos.ch/files/content/diverses/doserrors.txt)

My current code in-script is

```rb
module Graphics
  MFPCreateMediaPlayer = Win32API.new("Mfplay", "MFPCreateMediaPlayer", "pilplp", "i")
  GetActiveWindow = Win32API.new("User32", "GetActiveWindow", [], "L")
  CreateWindowExA = Win32API.new("User32", "CreateWindowExA", "lppliiiillpp", "l")
  GetWindowLongA = Win32API.new("User32", "GetWindowLongA", "li", "l")
  class << self
    def play_movie(filename)
      @vp ||= {:buffer => [].pack('x') * 256}
      p MFPCreateMediaPlayer.call(File.dirname(__FILE__) + filename, 1, 0, nil, GetActiveWindow.call(), nil)
    end
  end
end
```

If there are any ideas as to what this means, it would be *incredibly* appreciated.

thank you!

Comment: this is well known error code `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)` - *The system cannot find the file specified.* so `MFPCreateMediaPlayer` can not found `File.dirname(__FILE__) + filename`

Comment: @RbMm The error code for that appears to be 0x80030002, not 0x80070002

Comment: error 0x80030002 means %1 could not be found,  I have found the [link](https://windows-hexerror.linestarve.com/0x80030002) that may help you. I hope it will be useful to you.

Comment: but you wrote in question - *0x80070002*. so where you typo ? but anyway - different only on `FACILITY_STORAGE` (3) vs `FACILITY_WIN32` (7) - the error code in low 16 bytes - this is 2 - `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. read about [`HRESULT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/hresult) and look *winerror.h*

Comment: I tried hardcoding the exact path to the movie file, and it still returned the error however, so I'm honestly not sure what the issue is at this point?

Comment: @Shronk Ruby is my weakness, so I try to build a project in C++, and I refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/getting-started-with-mfplay#playing-a-media-file).I was able to compile and play video files successfully.

Comment: @Shronk [This case](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9a5d9557-5047-4af8-847e-6b4d3d6d0deb/error-quot0x80030002-1-could-not-be-foundquot-happens-on-microsoft-forms-20-frmae?forum=Offtopic) also involves 0x80030002, Although it's different from your environment, I search other posts quickly. Many of them are frameworks that don't match. To be honest, I can't confirm whether the errors are related to frameworks, but this is a direction.